# PhpStorm: Type hinting chained methods

Tags: php, phpstorm

In the code snippet below, I get type hinting on `$contactInfo[0]`, and again on `$order`.

I would like the same with `logger`, which is an object of type `\Monolog\Logger`, accessed as a member of `\psr\container\ContainerInterface`

I am using PhpStorm which is warning me that `Field 'logger' not found in Psr\Container\ContainerInterface`

```
/**
 * @param Order $order
 * @param ContactInfo[] $contactInfo
 * @var Monolog\Logger $this->container->logger
 */
private function buildCreateOrderJSON(Order $order, $contactInfo)
{
    try {
        $currentDate = new DateTime();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->container->logger->addInfo('Some exception', $e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
    $lastName = $contactInfo[0]->getLastName();
    $order->getInvoiceNumber();
}
```

Comment: before going any further : did you use the Jetbrains standard bug-fix method ??? that would be 'file->reindex&restart'

Comment: Haha yes, thank you though!

Comment: If ContainerInterface is `own code`, try adding a @var declaration in the interface for the logger var.

Comment: `@var Monolog\Logger $this->container->logger` -- this is simply wrong as you cannot typehint 3rd level entity like that. PHPDoc and PhpStorm allows typehinting only 1st level

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Usually you would create some stub file (for IDE eyes only) with a class that describes your Container class and declare `logger` there as a property. No better ideas.

Comment: Well, the problem is that an interface can't have members. You should declare $container as a concrete class (using /** @var $container SomeClass **/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As LazyOne mentioned in the comments, you can't type hint a 3rd level entity.

What you can do to retain method name refactoring is you can assign your class element to a variable, then type hint that:

```
/** @var $logger \Monolog\Logger */
$logger = $this->container->logger;
$logger->addInfo('Some exception', $e->getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces cannot have state in PHP, only methods signatures.

For this error to disappear, you can try assigning $this->container to a variable, and type hint that explicitly with a concrete class.

```
/** @var $container \Some\ConcreteContainerClass */
$container = $this->container;
$container->logger->addInfo('Some exception', $e->getMessage());
```

This would work if `logger` is an actual property of that class and not something accessed through magic getters. In that case, you might have to assign logger to another variable and do the same explicit type hint.

Another option is to supress inpesection for that line.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/suppressing-inspections.html#d218445e68